# Create dictionary from the position of elements in nested lists

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists, enumerate

I want to create a dictionary using the position of elements in each list of lists. The order of each nested list is very important and must remain the same.

Original nested lists and desired dictionary keys:

```
L_original = [[1, 1, 3], [2, 3, 8]]
keys = ["POS1", "POS2", "POS3"]
```

Desired dictionary created from `L_original`:

```
L_dictionary = {"POS1": [1, 2], "POS2": [1, 3], "POS3": [3, 8]}
```

The code I have so far fails the conditionals and ends on the `else` statement for each iteration.

```
for i in L_original:
    for key, value in enumerate(i):
        if key == 0:
            L_dictionary[keys[0]] = value
        if key == 1:
            L_dictionary[keys[1]] = value
        if key == 2:
            L_dictionary[keys[2]] = value
        else:
            print(f"Error in positional data processing...{key}: {value} in {i}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension as you enumerate

```
L_dictionary = dict()
for i, k in enumerate(keys):
    L_dictionary[k] = [x[i] for x in L_original]
```

Or simply

```
L_dictionary = {k: [x[i] for x in L_original] for i, k in enumerate(keys)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are more clean ways to solve this with some fancy python API, but one of the straightforward solutions might be the following:

For each `key` from `keys` we take those numbers from `L_original`'s nested arrays which have the same index as `key` has, namely `idx`

```
L_original = [[1, 1, 3], [2, 3, 8]]
keys = ["POS1", "POS2", "POS3"]
L_dictionary = {}

for (idx, key) in enumerate(keys):
    L_dictionary[key] = []
    for items in L_original:
        L_dictionary[key].append(items[idx])
```

Your code goes to `else`, because this `else` is related to the `if key == 2`, not to the whole chain of `if`s. So if the `key` is, for example, `0` the flow goes to `else`, because `0 != 2`. To fix this, the second and subsequent `if`s should be replaced with `elif`. This relates the `else` to the whole chain:

```
if key == 0:
  # only when key is 0
elif key == 1:
  # only when key is 1 
elif key == 2:
  # only when key is 2
else:
  # otherwise (not 0, not 1, not 2)
```

Comment: I appreciate the error catch on my part. I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
L_original = [[1, 1, 3], [2, 3, 8]]
keys = ["POS1", "POS2", "POS3"]

b=[list(x) for x in zip(L_original[0], L_original[1])]
a={i:b[index] for index,i in enumerate(keys)}
```

First, I have just created a new list by zipping(*[see zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip)*) index of first nested list to the same index of other nested list.

> Output of b: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [3, 8]]

Then created a dictionary using index of `keys` : index of `b` list.

> Output of a: {'POS1': [1, 2], 'POS2': [1, 3], 'POS3': [3, 8]}